# Input Values Sporadically Changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a form which is being modified via jQuery to change the position of certain fields. Then when the form is submitted it uses the position of those fields to determine the relative "position" value.

Unfortunately, it seems to only register a change to the relative position of the fields on occasion. More specifically, it only seems to register the top level changes sporadically whereas the second level changes seem to be registered consistently:

```
$("#newsletter_form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.newsletter_category').each(function(i, category) {
        $(category).find('.category_position').val(i + 1);

        $(category).children('.fields').each(function(j, article) {
            $(article).find('.article_position').val(j + 1);
        });
    });

    $("#newsletter_form").unbind('submit').submit();
});
```

Basically, when the "submit" event is called it goes through each newsletter_category, changes the position of the category_position field for that newsletter_category relative to any other newsletter_category's, then changes the position for each article inside of the newsletter_category. Or at least that's the desired behavior.

I've commented out the last line and confirmed that everything is getting set correctly and it is so my next best guess is that there is some sort of race condition going on. But the jQuery each function is synchronous so I can't imagine what sort of race condition is going on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out.

For the curious, the issue involved Rail's Turbolinks. Specifically, Turbolinks doesn't register a jQuery.ready() event, so any code inside of that will not get registered correctly. There are a number of ways to get around this but if its not really necessary for your app I would just remove Turbolinks completely (as I did).